# How do I hide the English/European Menu when I start Emacs?

Tags: emacs, xorg

Not sure what this menu is, but it blocks what I can see in the interpreter.

This is GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (sparc-sun-solaris2.10, X toolkit, Xaw3d scroll bars) of 2011-05-24 on sdev10. I'm accessing it through a university server (SSH). It's there as soon as I startup Emacs.

[image]

Comment: I've personally never seen that; you might want to give a bit more details as to how to reproduce.  (steps from startup, .emacs additions...)

Comment: I'll add some right now.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize it was a menu .. here is a screen shot (with the mouse depressed) showing some of the other options this pop-up has.. I'm off to IT to see if they can find the answer. Maybe a difference between displayed to and displayed from machines. (mine are both variants of Suse ) 
I believe this issue is LOCALE based, as another attempt to recreate my issue on my system gave me a bunch of perl errors related to the locale, and it defaulted to the standard locale ("C").

[image]

```
couldn't set locale correctly
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
couldn't set locale correctly
couldn't set locale correctly
```